# Can ShardingTest() pass non-default dbpath to mongod?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, homebrew

I'm running mongodb 3.0.6 ([homebrew](http://brew.sh)) on OS X 10.11/15A263e and can't figure my way through the js code for [ShardingTest](http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/symbols/src/src_mongo_shell_shardingtest.js.html) to specify a non-default data file path.

I want to avoid messing with symlinks or actual data files in /data for reasons but more importantly want to learn hot get the code below that class ShardingTest to work:

```
manoa:dev mike$ mongo --nodb
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
> var options = { shardOptions : { dbpath : "/usr/local/var/mongodb" } };
> cluster = new ShardingTest( { shards : 3 }, { other : options } );
Resetting db path '/data/db/test0'
2015-08-31T07:54:03.707-0500 E QUERY    Error: boost::filesystem::create_directory: No such file or directory: "/data/db/test0"
    at Function.MongoRunner.runMongod (src/mongo/shell/servers.js:589:13)
    at new ShardingTest (src/mongo/shell/shardingtest.js:259:36)
    at (shell):1:11 at src/mongo/shell/servers.js:589
```

I [looked over this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973077/set-smallfiles-in-shardingtest), but my JS is too weak to generalize from the help there to figure out how dbpath is set and which arguments will override the default path.

Could someone propose a way to debug this script or provide the actual syntax to feed my preferred db path to the ShardingTest function?

Answer (score 3):

`MongoRunner.dataPath` is [used to construct db paths](http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/symbols/src/src_mongo_shell_shardingtest.js.html):

```
this.getDBPaths = function() {
    return _alldbpaths.map((path) => {
        return MongoRunner.dataPath + path;
    });
};
```

So you might set it to whatever directory you want, e.g:

```
// don't forget the trailing slash
MongoRunner.dataPath = '/home/your_user/data/db/'
```